# How can I wire a 3 way switch with power feeds to another switch?

Tags: electrical

I need help with the wiring for a 3 way switch in my hallway.  One switch box has the power source coming in, the switch leg and 2 Power feeds going out to two other lights.  One power feed supplies the hot for a closet switch in an adajencent room and the other power feed supplies the hot for another 3 way switch that controls a light in the stairwell.

I’m unsure how to wire the switches allowing the 3 way to work for the hallway and the other lights to work properly.

I have spent 3 days and many hours of frustration trying to work this out.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated. A drawing would be wonderful.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange.  Your description isn't quite clear.  Could you start by describing what switches are in switch box 1, then describe the cables leaving switch box 1, then move on to box 2 (the other end of the 3-way switch) and do the same.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of all boxes involved?

Comment: Switch Box 1 has the power source coming in, the switch leg to the light, the 3 way wire to the 2nd switch box, and 2 additional 12/2 wires that supply power feed to switches for two lights in different locations.  Switch box 2 only has the 3 way light wire coming in.

Answer (score 1):

To wire to other loads from the box with a 3-way switch and a line feed, you simply identify the line cable, that is, the black line hot (always hot) and its associated white neutral (both being in the same cable).

Then connect another cable to the line hot and neutral routing it to the location you want to power-- connecting black to black, white to white and gnd to gnd. If your current connections are with wire nuts you must unscrew the nut on the line connections, add the new wire and reconnect with the same wire nut or a larger one if necessary.